# Вывод названия дня в Google Charts

Tags: javascript, дата, google-chart, timeline

мне нужно вывести название дня в дате в Google Charts.

Пробовал разные варианты, но ничего не помогает. Когда пишу формат даты: dd MMMM, выводит дату и название месяца (`22 July`), а когда пишу dddd MMMM, то выводит дату с 2 нолями перед ней (`0022 July`). Так же пробовал DDDD MMMM, но это не работает.

[image: описание изображения]

Как правильно указать формат даты, чтоб вывести название дня в Google Charts Timeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, что удалось найти.

```
'short': equivalent to 'M/d/yy, h:mm a' (6/15/15, 9:03 AM).
    'medium': equivalent to 'MMM d, y, h:mm:ss a' (Jun 15, 2015, 9:03:01 AM).
    'long': equivalent to 'MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a z' (June 15, 2015 at 9:03:01 AM GMT+1).
    'full': equivalent to 'EEEE, MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a zzzz' (Monday, June 15, 2015 at 9:03:01 AM GMT+01:00).
    'shortDate': equivalent to 'M/d/yy' (6/15/15).
    'mediumDate': equivalent to 'MMM d, y' (Jun 15, 2015).
    'longDate': equivalent to 'MMMM d, y' (June 15, 2015).
    'fullDate': equivalent to 'EEEE, MMMM d, y' (Monday, June 15, 2015).
    'shortTime': equivalent to 'h:mm a' (9:03 AM).
    'mediumTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a' (9:03:01 AM).
    'longTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a z' (9:03:01 AM GMT+1).
    'fullTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a zzzz' (9:03:01 AM GMT+01:00).
```